# MySQLでマッチした最初の行を結合したい

Tags: mysql

MySQLである日付のTOPIX終値(`thattopix.adjust_price`)と1年後のTOPIX終値(`topixfuture.adjust_price`)を比較するクエリーを作成します。
休日のデータは格納されていないため、もし1年後のTOPIX終値がない場合は、1年後以降でひっかかる最初の終値を引っ張りたいと考えていますが方法がわからず往生しています。
私が求める方法は存在するのでしょうか？

```
SELECT
    thattopix.year,
    topixfuture.adjust_price,
    thattopix.adjust_price,
    topixfuture.year as futureyear
FROM
    stockdata as thattopix
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT year, price, adjust_price
        FROM stockdata
        WHERE code_id=3912
    ) AS topixfuture ON thattopix.year <= DATE_SUB(topixfuture.year,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
WHERE
    code_id = 3912
    AND thattopix.year >= DATE_SUB(topixfuture.year,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
;
```

◆ stockdataテーブル

```
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| year         | date       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| code_id      | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| price        | float      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| adjust_price | float      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

※ 2010年～2011年のデータを入力しています

sayuriさん
payanekoさん
ご検討いただきありがとうございます！！！
無事抽出できました！
本当に助かりました。
質問のクローズ方法がわからなかったので、ひとまず本文にてお礼申し上げます_(.*.)*

Comment: 1年後の日付から、1日ずつずらしてクエリーをかけるのが現実的だと思います。
TOPIX終値が無い日が２週間以上続くことは考えにくいので、今日の１年後から、その１３日後までの範囲でクエリーをかければ十分だと思います。

Comment: もし解決した場合には役立った回答にプラス投票や承認をしてあげてください。 - 参考: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) / 感謝の気持ちも該当の回答に対して付けてあげるとよいかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

副問い合わせでグループ関数(`min`関数)を使うことで、topixfutureの日付をthattopixの翌年以降かつ最古の日付に合わせることができます。

**サンプルSQL**

```
WITH stockdata
AS (SELECT 1 AS id, cast('20101201' AS date) AS year, 3912 AS code_id, 10 AS price, 10 AS adjust_price UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, cast('20111201' AS date) AS year, 3912 AS code_id, 11 AS price, 11 AS adjust_price UNION ALL -- 翌年同日
    SELECT 3 AS id, cast('20101226' AS date) AS year, 3913 AS code_id, 12 AS price, 12 AS adjust_price UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS id, cast('20120104' AS date) AS year, 3913 AS code_id, 13 AS price, 13 AS adjust_price UNION ALL -- 翌々年最初
    SELECT 5 AS id, cast('20120105' AS date) AS year, 3913 AS code_id, 13 AS price, 13 AS adjust_price)          -- 翌々年最初 + 1日
SELECT thattopix.*, topixfuture.*
FROM stockdata AS thattopix
    LEFT JOIN stockdata AS topixfuture
    ON thattopix.code_id = topixfuture.code_id
    AND topixfuture.year = (SELECT min(tmp.year)
                            FROM stockdata AS tmp
                            WHERE tmp.code_id = thattopix.code_id
                            AND tmp.year >= DATE_ADD(thattopix.year, INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```

**実行結果**

```
id    year    code_id    price    adjust_price    id    year    code_id    price    adjust_price
1    2010-12-01    3912    10    10    2    2011-12-01    3912    11    11
2    2011-12-01    3912    11    11    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3    2010-12-26    3913    12    12    4    2012-01-04    3913    13    13
4    2012-01-04    3913    13    13    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
5    2012-01-05    3913    13    13    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

まず総当たりの中から１年後以降のものを取り出し、なおかつその順位を振っておく。順位が`1`のものが最も近い日付となっている。

```
SELECT that.id AS thatid, future.id AS futureid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY that.id ORDER BY future.year) AS no
FROM stockdata AS that, stockdata AS future
WHERE DATE_ADD(that.year, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) <= future.year
```

これを使えば

```
SELECT that.year, future.adjust_price, that.adjust_price, future.year as futureyear
FROM stockdata AS that
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT that.id AS thatid, future.id AS futureid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY that.id ORDER BY future.year) AS no
    FROM stockdata AS that, stockdata AS future
    WHERE DATE_ADD(that.year, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) <= future.year
) AS map ON that.id = map.thatid AND map.no = 1
INNER JOIN stockdata AS future ON map.futureid = future.id
```

とか。

---

先にテーブルを完成させてから順位`1`で絞り込んでもいいですが、どっちがいいのかなぁ。

```
SELECT thatyear, futureprice, thatprice, futureyear
FROM (
    SELECT
       that.year AS thatyear,
       future.adjust_price AS futureprice,
       that.adjust_price AS thatprice,
       future.year as futureyear,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY that.id ORDER BY future.year) AS no
    FROM stockdata AS that, stockdata AS future
    WHERE DATE_ADD(that.year, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) <= future.year
) AS t
WHERE no = 1
```